# How to package root-level modules in namespace packages?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

Consider this project structure:

```
<project root>
  setup.py
  <namespace_package>
    module_a.py
    module_b.py
    <package>
      __init__.py
```

The [PyPA documentation](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#) suggests that such a layout is permissible. It works for me locally using pip editable installs. My issue is that when I create a sdist or wheel `module_a.py` and `module_b.py` are not being included. Here is my `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import find_namespace_packages, setup

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="0.1",
    description="foo",
    long_description="fooooooooooooooooo",
    author="me",
    author_email="me@non-ya.business",
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["namespace_package.*"]),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

I know I can work around this problem by converting all of those root-level modules into `__init__.py` files inside a similarly named directory, but that seems like a very non-Pythonic solution. **Is there a better/cleaner way to include my root-level modules?**

Comment: Strange. I thought it would have worked. You might try to use `py_modules` for those modules.

Comment: You might also like to use [strict editable installs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#strict-editable-installs), if you want them to behave more similarly to a "real" install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to experiment I was able to get this to work:

```py
from pathlib import Path

from setuptools import find_namespace_packages, setup


def find_root_modules(root: str) -> list[str]:
    def is_module(path: Path) -> bool:
        return path.is_file() and path.suffix == ".py"

    return [str(p).removesuffix(".py") for p in filter(is_module, Path(root).iterdir())]

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="0.1",
    description="foo",
    long_description="fooooooooooooooooo",
    author="me",
    author_email="me@non-ya.business",
    packages=find_namespace_packages(include=["namespace_package.*"]),
    include_package_data=True,
    py_modules=find_root_modules("namespace_package"),
)
```